# Jest locking with EBUSY for every test

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ts-jest

## Summarise the problem

I'm hitting the following issue whenever running tests in Jest for an angular project:

```
EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\jest\ts-jest\1b\56fbb16412d9bba7787f9ba7186e4b9972adfb\e9a8ee471bc676fe755c57379268f21a1390a7a4

    > 1 | import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
        | ^
      2 |

      at NgJestTransformer.TsJestTransformer.getCacheKey (../../node_modules/ts-jest/dist/legacy/ts-jest-transformer.js:341:40)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/index.js:33:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:7:69)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.mjs:7:1159)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.mjs:2:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/setup-jest.ts:1:1)
```

...run via the command: `nx run <project>:test`

These were working up until Monday.

The tests **do** run if I run either:

- A individual test/test suite in rider
- A single test suite in the terminal via: `nx run <project>:test --project=<project> --testFile=src/app/services/plotly-layout.service.spec.ts`

## Describe what you've tried

I see these EBUSY issues a fair amount, but usually, one of the following works:

- Closing the terminal I'm working in
- Closing Rider
- Restarting my computer

None of these are working.

Given that the lock was on the `Temp` folder, I've tried deleting the entire `Temp/jest` folder, but it just regenerates the `56fbb16412d9bba7787f9ba7186e4b9972adfb\e9a8ee471bc676fe755c57379268f21a1390a7a4` file and locks immediately on the next test run.

Has anyone come across this before? My assumption is that `jest` is parallelizing test suites where it shouldn't be, but I don't know why it would have suddenly started.

Comment: I can add that it's not NX-related issue as I see it with a bare Jest runner as well. on Windows, Node v18. 
Problem could be related to Windows Defender but I tried to add the Jest cache folder to exclusions - that didn't help.

Comment: As a workaround you can add "--no-cache" parameter as EBUSY fails for accessing the cache hash file. But that will slowdown the whole thing a bit.

Comment: @Statyan - while I've not figured out why this happens, it does appear to be a windows only thing. We've tried on Mac and Linux, and it's fine there.

Either way, the best "fix" I've found is using `--runInBand` - again, it makes things a little slower, but (a) not nearly as much as `--no-cache`, and (b) since doing that, I've not had any issues.

Hope that helps a little!

Comment: I am having the same issue. adding --runInBand helped. Thanks.